# IndexedDB Get next unique index based on predicate

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Is there a way to retrieve the next unique index in a store based on a predicate on the record. For example if I have a book store full of objects like so:

```
{name: 'Hello Kitty', author: 'Me', pages: 5}
```

Would it be possible to return the next unique index on author, but base the uniqueness on the highest number of pages?

```
index.openKeyCursor('author', IDBCursor.nextunique).onsuccess = function(event) {
  var cursor = event.target.result;
  if (cursor) {
    // How to filter the record by highest number of pages?
    cursor.continue();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, but you can do. I will illustrate with my library https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db but you can use IndexedDB API.

First you have to use compound index (only Firefox and Chrome supported) using array keyPath. Database schema for ydn-db is

```
var schema = {
  stores: [{
    name: 'book',
    indexes: [{
      name: 'author, pages',
      keyPath: ['author', 'pages']
    }]
  }
};
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('db name', schema);
```

The index, `'author, pages'` is sorted by `author` and then by `pages`. Then we prepare cursor or create iterator in ydn-db.

```
var iter = new ydn.db.IndexValueIterator('book', 'author, pages');
```

By default, order is in ascending. Here we want descending order to get highest pages value. This inadvertently make author to sort in descending order, but there is no way to avoid it.

```
iter = iter.reverse().unique(); // essentially 'PREV_UNIQUE'
```

Then, we [open the iterator](http://dev.yathit.com/api-reference/ydn-db/storage.html#open) giving rise to cursor with descending ordering. The first cursor is what we want. On next iteration, we skip duplicate author name. This is done by using `cursor.continue(next_key)` method. `next_key` is given, such that it won't repeat what already got by giving lowest possible value with known author key.

```
db.open(function(cursor) {
  var book = cursor.getValue();
  console.log(book);
  var effective_key = cursor.getKey();
  var author_key = effective_key[0];
  var next_key = [author_key];
  return next_key; // continue to this or lower than this key.
}, iter);
```

Note that, we just need to iterate only unique author and no buffer memory require, and hence scalable.